# Create Image Dynamically / CSS to Canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create an image dynamically in Javascript that needs to fit two requirements.

1. It needs a colored background (say #fff) and be of a specific size (say 800x300)
2. I need to be able to then place another image on it and position it (hopefully with CSS-esque type rules like width:150px; height:80px; left: 30px; top:30px; transform: rotate(7deg);" etc etc.

Is there a library you're aware of that does that sort of function?

Comment: Yes a library Jquery.

Comment: How exactly canvas is involved in the question?

Comment: So far I've been researching the CreateIMageData() method - and it looks promising.  I'm more a PHP guy - I'd rather render it in the browser than post it to the backend & do some sort of GD process.

What I'm trying to do is position two elements relative to each other and keep the registration in tact.  One object is a fixed size and always will be.  The second image is variable in size - which makes the registration a bit more difficult.  My thought is if I render it on to another image dynamically that is the same size - that'll simplify my task :)

Comment: How about [drawImgae](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage). It lets you to define the size and position for the image. Notice, that there's no live elements in a canvas, they all are melted to pixel mass. If you need live elements, you should consider SVG instead.

Comment: Good suggestion - thank you.  :)  Only thing that I see that it doesn't do that I would need is something similar to the transform:rotate().  

I think I found a decent jQuery library that has all those functions within it...called JCanvas.  http://projects.calebevans.me/jcanvas/

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't really need a library for this at all. If i understand you correctly you simply want a container with a background that holds a dynamically generated image. I would just use a background image or color on the container and appendChild the image inside of it.

Use a relative position on the parent and an absolute position on the image so you can center position the image and rotate it form the center.

to create and append image i would use:

```
//generate image dynamically
function dynamicImage(url){
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = url;
  img.setAttribute("class", "placeholder-image")
  return img
}

var dynamic = dynamicImage('http://placehold.it/350x150')

var container = document.querySelectorAll('.image-container')              
container[0].appendChild(dynamic)
```

I would then use css to transform the image

example in codepen
http://codepen.io/shperber/pen/qNVLjv